# Normal subgroup invariant under $\text{Ad}_g$

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Denote by $G$ a Lie group with corresponding Lie algebra $\text{Lie}(G)$.

There the three maps

inner automorphism/conjugation: $\text{Int}_g = L_{g^{-1}} \circ R_g \in \text{Aut}(G)$,

$\text{Ad}_g := D_1 \text{Int}_g = D_g L_{g^{-1}} \circ D_1 R_g \in \text{Aut}(\text{Lie}(G))$,

and moreover: $\text{ad}_v := \frac{d}{dt}\big\vert_{t=0} \text{Ad}_{\gamma_v(t)}\in\text{Hom}(\text{Lie}(G))$ where $\gamma_v(t)$ is any one-parameter semi-group generated by $v$.

Now, in my lecture there it says (**$G$ is not said to be embedded in a matrix**):

> The component $K$ of identity of $G$ is normal, i.e. it is invariant under $\text{Ad}_g$ for any $g\in G$.

Since normality is defined by $k=g^{-1} k g$ for any $g\in G$ and all $k\in K$ this statement would imply that $\text{Int}_g = \text{Ad}_g$ on $K$.

Is this true? I do not see how to see that $\text{Ad}_g$ behaves there like this.

Comment: Its wrong. It should be invariant under $\text{Int}_g$.

Comment: What Troy said.  Also normality is not defined by $k = g^{-1}kg$ for all $a \in G$ and $k \in K$.  That's what it means for $K$ to be *central*.  Normality is defined by $g^{-1}kg \in K$ for all $g \in G$ and $k \in K$.  So conjugation can move $k$, it just doesn't move it outside $K$.